# How to set the cursor in text box on page init

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, textbox, cursor, focus

I am doing a mobile application in jquery mobile. When the first page is loading it have an init function. My requirement is that when the first page is loaded the cursor should point to the text box. I tried:

```
  $('#txtdemo').focus();
```

and

```
   var txtBox=document.getElementById("txtdemo");
   txtBox.focus();
```

but both are not working. Please let me know a good approach to do this.

Comment: Have you tried placing the .focus call in a setTimeout with a time of say, 200?

Comment: @vinithasreevijay, i think  you can not do like this, because it may be like input field 'txtdemo' may not be available in init function

Comment: When I am giving focus () the text box is selecting, but the problem is that the cursor is not pointing to the text box

Comment: @vinithasreevijay - in my mobile site, i tried it too. but at last i found out that it's usability issue..:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mobile site, it is impossible to focus in textbox and open keyboard using programming. it is one type of usability issue. In desktop site you can do this with

```
$('#txtdemo').focus();

$('#txtdemo').select();

$('#txtdemo').trigger('focus');

$('#txtdemo').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done only during the **`pageshow`** event. It must be **`pageshow`** because page is fully formed only at that point. If you dont know what **`pageshow`** is take a look at my **ARTICLE** regarding jQuery Mobile page events. Also this will only work on a desktop browsers, it will not work on mobile browsers. In a case of mobile browsers input field will be under focus but this will not trigger keyboard to show.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $('#some-input').focus();
});
```

Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/#update
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>  
        <script>
            $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
                $('#some-input').focus();
            }); 
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <input type="text" value="" id="some-input"/>  
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? My examples was tested on Firefox, Chrome and IE9 and it work in all of them.

Comment: Have you tried my example directly because I cant believe it is not working for you when it is working in my case? Also What platform do you use Widnows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: It is working for web application, but my application is mobile. It is not working in mobile.

Comment: Then have you read what I have written? It will NOT work on mobile devices and it is NOT possible to make it work. All mobile devices will prevent this from happening. What us point of this answers if you don't want to read them.